# How to change permissions to certain file pattern/extension?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, file-permissions, chmod

Using `chmod`, I do `chmod +x *.sh` in the current directory but what if I want to change all files including files within subfolders that has an sh file extension?.

`chmod +x -R *` will work but I need something more like `chmod +x -R *.sh`

Answer (score 80, accepted):

use find:

```
find . -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```

Comment: the command line is hard to memorize or remember, I have to come and visit this page often times to see the syntax. Do you have a sort of way to remember this command?

Comment: I can't remember a lot of the commands.  So, I build scripts that accept parameters.

Comment: For those confused about what the command is actually *doing*, see chappjc's answer, below, for a hint, at least.

Answer (score 13):

Try using the glorious combination of find with xargs.

```
find . -iname \*.sh -print0 | xargs -r0 chmod +x
```

The `.` is the directory to start in, in this case the working directory.

Comment: Or you can use -exec in the simple case, as in ennuikiller's example.  `xargs` has slightly more power for more complicated uses.

Comment: This is more efficient than find ... -exec ...  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Comment: @Nathan  Thanks for pointing out this important distinction.  Reading about this, I discovered a newish `find` syntax that gets the best of both worlds (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32618572/2778484) for details).

Answer (score 8):

**With modern versions of `find`**, you get the benefits of an `xargs` approach that avoids multiple calls to the command (`chmod`).  The command is only slightly different.

`find . -name "*.sh" -exec chmod +x {} +`

Snip from [`find` docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) on Arch 2015.09.01 (**emphasis** added by me):

> `-exec command {} +`
>
> This  variant  of the `-exec` action runs the specified command on the selected files, **but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than  the  number  of matched files**.  The command line is built in much the same way that `xargs` builds its command lines.  Only one instance of `{}` is allowed within the command.  The command is executed in the  starting  directory.