# Why doesn't chmod -R +x *.sh work?

Tags: bash, chmod

So, "chmod -R +x *.sh" does not work in bash. Alternatives can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249878/how-do-i-change-file-permission-to-a-certain-file-pattern-to-sub-folders-of-my-c). My question is: why doesn't it work? Does chmod simply lack this feature because nobody bothered to implement it or is there some deeper bash/gnulib philosophy to this?

Comment: I think what you want is `find . -name '*.sh' -exec chmod +x {} +`

Comment: Use `find` with `-exec` instead

Comment: Why do you think it "does not work"?  It sets the executable bit on all files whose name ends in '.sh' and in all files in subdirectories whose name ends in '.sh'.  Works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in `bash`, the wildcard pattern is expanded by the shell and not by the program. This is unlike in Windows where the pattern is passed to the program itself. Let's consider this sample directoy structure:

```
curdir
|_ 1.sh
|_ 2.sh
|_ subdir
   |_ 3.sh
   |_ 4.sh
```

Say you're running the command `chmod -R +x *.sh` from within the `curdir` directory. The shell sees that `*.sh` is a wildcard pattern and expands it to `1.sh 2.sh` since those are the filenames that match the pattern. The final command that is executed becomes `chmod -R +x 1.sh 2.sh`. As you can see, none of the arguments is a directory, so the `-R` switch has no effect.

There are shells that have support for more complex patterns. For example, if you're using `zsh`, you can run the following command:

```
chmod +x **/*.sh # Note that -R is not required
```

`zsh` [understands](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_2.html) the `**` pattern to mean a recursive search into subdirectories. Thus, the final command in this case will be:

```
chmod +x 1.sh 2.sh subdir/3.sh subdir/4.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

The `*` isn't processed by `chmod`; it's a shell feature known as [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). The shell expands `*.sh` to a list of all names in the current directory that end in `.sh` and passes them to `chmod` as separate arguments. The shell doesn't know that there's any recursive directory search aspect to the command, and `chmod` never knows the command line had a `*` in it.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the command, it is first preprocessed by your shell and then executed. During preprocessing phase, the star symbol `*` gets expanded into matches (in this case shell files in current directory). Then, `-R` gets ignored, as there are no input directories that could be recursed.

`chmod` is not lacking this feature. It doesn't even get the information that you had originally star symbol in your command.