# How do I copy "with execute permissions" in a docker file used to create a ubuntu container on docker for windows

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I have a docker file that copies a file tree to the container using the command in the docker file:

```
COPY image /
```

Docker copies all the files BUT the `.sh` and `.py` etc files in the source folder ( on windows ) have execute permission turned on. When the container is run the copies present in the container DO NOT have execute permission turned on?

How do I deal with this other than explicitly `chmod +x` the files in the docker file when building the container (having to maintain a list of them etc) in this situation.

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249878/how-do-i-change-file-permission-to-a-certain-file-pattern-to-sub-folders-of-my-c ?

Comment: @gravetii not really I know about chmod  the issue is it is a large file tree with files of many suffi and some files with no suffix ( executable scripts and other unix binaries ) so unless I want to hit all the files including those that should *NOT* be executable it doesn't really help.

Comment: Maybe you should post it on the docker forums too.

Comment: @gravetii one you suggest ?